# Wrong answer on elementary diophantine equation - why?

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

> Solve the equation and show all possible, non-negative values for X
>   and Y: $5X+4Y=60$

So I wanted to do it like that:
$$5X+4Y=60\leftrightarrow0X+4Y=0 \pmod5$$, thus $4Y=5k$ where $k\in Z$. Similarly: $$5X+5k=60\leftrightarrow X=12-k$$ However, in my textbook I find that at this stage, I should get to $$X=60-4k, \\ Y=-60+5k$$

Why doesn't the method of diving coefficients modulo work here?

Comment: For one thing, your $\leftrightarrow$s should be $\rightarrow$s. After that, plug your $X = 12 - k$ back into the original equation, and see if it helps. (Look at it mod 4, maybe.) Finally, if $4Y$ is a multiple of $5$, can you say anything about $Y$ itself?

Comment: Is your solution attempt an application of some general method that you know, or is it simply some guess as how to proceed? If the former, please say what method you are attempting to employ, so we can help you debug it.